# .Net RNGCryptoServiceProvider class versus Win32 CryptGenRandom() function

Tags: .net, winapi, cryptography, random, cryptoapi

I have a new application being written in .Net. I also have a legacy version of the application that must be maintained (for the meantime), which has been written in VB6 and utilizes C++ DLLs. Certain C++ native DLLs must continue to be utilized and shared by the new .Net application via P/Invoke.

The legacy app currently utilizes a random number generator, which will be replaced to use CryptGenRandom() function available through Win32 APIs. The new .Net app has the same need and can utilize the RNGCryptoServiceProvider class.

**Question:**
Under the hood does the .Net RNGCryptoServiceProvider class utilize the Win32 CryptGenRandom() function? If so, I would be interested in any links on available documentation in regards to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the .Net `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class obtains random data from a "Cryptographic Service Provider" (CSP) (so says [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx)). In the CryptoAPI, a CSP is a loadable DLL which provides some cryptographic services, mainly private key storage, signature computations... and also random number generation. A CSP can be used only if it has been signed (by Microsoft) and registered (by writing in some specific registry keys).

The `CryptGenRandom()` function uses the default CSP (the one registered as to be used by default, normally one of the CSP which come with the operating system itself) and invokes the `CPGenRandom()` function on that CSP. `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` does the same. Hence, it does *not* call `CryptGenRandom()`, but it feeds on the same cryptographically strong source.

Comment: `CryptGenRandom()` uses the CSP indicated by its first parameter `hProv`.